# Remove Edit button from navigation bar

Tags: ios, storyboard, navigationbar

My root view controller is a static table view, where clicking on a row brings you to views where the real work is done in the app.  I have an Edit button in the navigation bar appearing on this screen.  How do I get rid of it?  The content is not editable.  I'm looking for a style to set in the storyboard for the view controller or the table view, but can't find it.

Comment: That edit button is appearing, and you don't want it to at all, or are you are asking how to programmatically remove the edit button when you don't need it?

Comment: Ask yourself how the Edit button got there in the first place. It didn't happen by magic. It got there because _you_ put it there. If you don't want it there, don't put it there.

Answer (score 0):

search for and remove

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

if not then add

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```